# Returning a variable number of Elements from a function in React Native

Tags: react-native

In `App.ts`, the following displays the text **value** on the device:

```
function displayValue() {
   <Text> value <Text>
}

export default function App() {
   return (
      <View>{displayValue()}<View>
   )
}
```

What is the correct way to modify the `displayValue()` function so that it will iterate through a collection such as a `Set` or `Array`, place each value in the collection a separate`<Text>` element, and then return all of these `<Text>` elements to the `<View>` from which the function is called ?

`<FlatList>` will not work here, as the `<Text>` items will need to be displayed in rows and columns.

Thanks

Comment: <View>{[1,2,3].map(displayValue)}</View>